# Set a test timeout duration with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have some test cases that can go into an infinite loop upon failure. Is there a built-in way to set a test timeout duration with PHPUnit?

If not, what would be the most unobtrusive way of adding this feature to a test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the [PerformanceTestCase](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/testcase-extensions.html#testcase-extensions.performance) you can set a setMaxRunningTime() with it for a test.

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/risky-tests.html#test-execution-timeout). TLDR:

1. Add `enforceTimeLimit="true"` in PHPUnit’s configuration file.
2. Annotate your tests by either `@small` (=1sec), `@medium` (=10sec), or `@large` (=60sec) to set the expected execution time. Any test that exceeds this threshold will be marked as "Risky"
3. Additionally if you wish to exit the test, you can pass the `--fail-on-risky` flag when executing PHPUnit